# Input Logic Not Resolving As Anticipated

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out my code isn't working.

I'm trying to input an age, and assign a color to it based on it like I've show below, but my input always comes out green if its above 12.

```
Console.WriteLine("input your age: ");
int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (age<= 12)
{
    Console.WriteLine("color: white");
}
else if (age>= 13)
{
    Console.WriteLine("color: green");
}
else if (age >= 19)
{
    Console.WriteLine("color: red");
}
else if (age >= 26)
{
    Console.WriteLine("color: blue");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("invalid age");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Imagine the number is 27, step through the code mentally or using a debugger and see what happens. It hits` >=13` and that's the end of that. Put your `>=` conditions in descending order of value and it will work.

Comment: We all have started somewhere, but phrasing your question gets more responses than "Please help". GL and keep at it (programming). :-) See  [How to Ask A Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Numbers that should have given the output of red and blue are also larger than 13, so that condition evaluates to true. You're missing the counterpart of the range - for green, the age shouldn't just be greater or equal than 13, it should also be less than 19. The same issue exists for the blue condition:

```
if (age <= 12)
{
    Console.WriteLine("color: white");
}
else if (age >= 13 && age < 19) // Here!
{
    Console.WriteLine("color: green");
}
else if (age >= 19 && age < 26) // And here!
{
    Console.WriteLine("color: red");
}
else if (age >= 26)
{
    Console.WriteLine("color: blue");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here in your second condition you have written if the `age >= 13` then it should print `color: green`. So, in your case any number you will enter above 12 will be satisfied within this condition and you will always get `color: green` as output.

Answer (score 0):

If your number is greater than 13 it automatically returns green and then ends at this point. You can change the sequence beginning with the greatest and then ending with the smallest.